# Install Ubuntu without formatting the HDD on a laptop with SSD where Windows is installed+HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Buen dia, me gustaria comenzar a utilizar linux, tengo una laptop con un SSD donde esta instalado windows y un HDD donde guardo la mayoria mis archivos e instalo la mayoria de los programas. La pregunta es ¿Es posible instalar Ubuntu en el HDD sin tener que formatear ninguno de los dos discos duros? en caso de poder ¿Tendria porblemas para inciarlos?

---

I would like to start using Linux on my laptop which has 2 hard disks. I have a laptop with an SSD where Windows is installed and an HDD where I keep most of my files and install most of the programs. The question is, is it possible to install Ubuntu on the HDD without having to format either of the two hard drives? In case of power, would there be problems starting them?

Answer (score 0):

Install an Ubuntu guest OS in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) in Windows. You need to boot Windows first in order to run the Ubuntu guest OS, because the Ubuntu guest OS runs inside VirtualBox which is installed in Windows.

1. In order to install Ubuntu on the HDD open VirtualBox and select *File* -> *Preferences* -> *General*.
2. Create a new folder on the HDD and name it anything you like, e.g. *VirtualBox*.
3. Click the dropdown menu arrow to the right of where it says *Default Machine Folder* and choose *Other…*. Here you can choose the new folder for VirtualBox to store data.

   [image]
4. Click the OK button in the lower right corner of the Preferences window.